# How to count the minimum number of possible connected components given only negative information

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx

**Preface and setup:**

Consider the following iterative clustering procedure. A user is given a set of nodes. In each iteration of the clustering process, a user marks two nodes as either matching or not matching by placing either a positive or negative edge between the two nodes. A positive edge indicates that the pair of nodes must belong to the same cluster, likewise a negative edge indicates the nodes must belong to different clusters. The current number of clusters is defined by the connected components of the graph using only the positive edges. A user is not allowed to make invalid moves (eg. place a negative edge within a positive connected component).

At each iteration of the clustering process I want to know the maximum and minimum number of clusters that could result from the processes.
The maximum number is simple: it is just the current number of positive connected components. However, the minimum was not immediately obvious.

---

**The main problem:**

My question is about computing the minimum number of clusters. Given a set of nodes, and a set of edges denoting that two nodes must belong to different clusters, what is the minimum number of clusters possible?

---

**A possibly inelegant solution:**

I believe I have an algorithm that  will compute this number, but I think it can be improved (if it is correct). In my current algorithm I first condense all positive edges, such that each positive component is represented by just a single node. This allows us to just ignore positive information.

Given only a set of nodes and negative information: 1) choose a random node. 2) find all other nodes that this node could be connected to without causing an inconsistency. 3) remove these nodes from the graph and increment the count by one. 4) iterate on the remaining nodes. 5) when no nodes remain in the graph, return the current count.

The following python code formalizes this a bit more:

```
    import networkx as nx

    def minimum_number_compoments_possible(nodes, negative_edges):
        """
        Find minimum number of connected compoments possible
        Each edge represents that two nodes must be separated

        >>> nodes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
        >>> negative_edges = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
        >>> minimum_number_compoments_possible(nodes, negative_edges)
        2
        """
        num = 0
        # Create the negative graph
        g_neg = nx.Graph()
        g_neg.add_nodes_from(nodes)
        g_neg.add_edges_from(negative_edges)
        # Initialize unused nodes to be everything
        unused = list(g_neg.nodes())
        # complement of the graph contains all possible positive edges
        g_pos = nx.complement(g_neg)
        # Iterate until we have used all nodes
        while len(unused) > 0:
            # Seed a new "minimum compoment"
            num += 1
            # Grab a random unused node n1
            n1 = unused[0]
            unused.remove(n1)
            neigbs = list(g_pos.neighbors(n1))
            while len(neigbs) > 0:
                # Find node n2, that n1 could be connected to
                n2 = neigbs[0]
                unused.remove(n2)
                # Collapse negative information of n1 and n2
                g_neg = nx.contracted_nodes(g_neg, n1, n2)
                # Compute new possible positive edges
                g_pos = nx.complement(g_neg)
                # Iterate until n1 has no more possible connections
                neigbs = list(g_pos.neighbors(n1))
        return num
```

The running time of this algorithm should be O(n^3) where n is the total number of edges and vertices in the graph (unless I made a mistake or the fact that nodes are condensing plays into the calculation; I'm assuming it doesn't). If this algorithm is correct, it seems like it could be improved in both runtime and simplicity, but maybe not. This is the part where I need help.

---

**The part where I need help:**

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution, or if this problem is a known problem and has a proper name. I initially thought that this property might have something to do with the degree of the negative graph, but I'm not seeing anything obvious.

**EDIT**: Some comments have brought up that this problem might be reducible to a problem in NP, in which case my algorithm is likely not correct. I'm looking into this more, but I haven't thought of a counter example yet.

**EDIT2**: I'm convinced that this is NP-complete and I do see the reduction to minimum clique cover. I found a counter example using the graph with edges: [(1, 8), (1, 9), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2,
9), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (4, 8), (4, 9), (5, 7), (5,
8), (5, 9), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9)] and randomizing the indices chosen instead of using just the first. My incorrect algorithm returns either 3 or 4.

I guess the task now is to determine if there is a good approximation algorithm for this task. In my setting a user is much more likely to mark a pair of nodes with a positive edge, so maybe this algorithm will still usually produce the correct solution in most scenarios.

Comment: I am having some trouble understanding how your positive and negative egdes work. Can three nodes be connected by two positive and one negative edges (or one positive and two negative) ? Can an edge be neither positive nor negative ? Are every couple of vertices connected by an edge ?

Comment: @Nelxiost 3 nodes cannot be connected as you described: "A user is not allowed to make invalid moves (eg. place a negative edge within a positive connected component)"  My interpretation is that the user is adding edges 1 at a time to an empty graph.

Comment: Oh my bad, I misread. So, since the positive edges are being taken care of, we only have neutral and negative edges. But then do we have some set of neutral edges to work with or are all vertices connected ?

Comment: The minimum number of clusters is equal to the size of the biggest glob. Where a glob is N nodes that are [fully connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) by negative edges.

Comment: It seems like only the negative edges are relevant in the final answer, since for a minimum, any other edge may be connected.

Comment: Your problem is NP, and so your algorithm doesn't always produce the correct answer. I guess you can prove that empirically by running it multiple times on a complicated enough graph and seeing that it doesn't always produce the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing the minimum number of clusters in your problem is NP complete.

One can reduce the [clique cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover) to it: given a graph, let the nodes be vertices of the graph, and let there be a negative edge between two nodes if and only if there is no edge between the corresponding vertices in the graph. Then finding a minimal set of clusters is equivalent to finding a minimal clique covering in the original graph.

The reduction the other way is similar: coalesce nodes with positive edges, and construct a graph with edges between two nodes if and only if there is no negative edge in the original problem. Then finding a minimal clique covering of this graph is equivalent to finding a minimal set of clusters in the original set of nodes.

Finding a minimal covering of a graph by cliques is one of [Karp's 21 NP complete problems.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution

Collapse positively-connected components. If there is a negative self-loop, then it's unsatisfiable. Otherwise, find a minimal coloration of the resulting graph (which only has negative edges), and you got a solution.

The complexity is terrible (coloration…), but it seems easier to explain.

EDIT: Actually, I'm surprised you have a O(n^3) algorithm. I think the coloration problem can be reduced to yours, symmetrically to what I have done above.

---

> if this problem is a known problem and has a proper name

If you see it as an integer problem instead of a graph problem, you could call this 1-SAT modulo equality.

“1-SAT” because it's a conjunction of atoms, and “[modulo equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories)” because you want to assign a number to each node according to equal/not-equal constraints.